# Store IP Address of every visitor with returning count using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a **PHP** file, the function is to get visitor's IP addresses and store them into MySQL Database. File for grab and store IP Address is:

```
include 'config.php';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=DB_NAME", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully.";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

function getIPAddress() {  
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {  
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];  
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {  
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];  
    } else{  
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
    }  
    return $ip;  
}  

$ip = getIPAddress();  
echo '<br/> User Real IP Address - '.$ip;  

echo '<hr/>';

$sql = 'INSERT INTO stored_ip(ipaddr) VALUES(:ipaddr)';
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([
    ':ipaddr' => $ip,
]);
$ip = $conn->lastInsertId();

echo 'The publisher id ' . $ip . ' was inserted';
```

This script works fine but I want to upgrade it. When the same visitor, visits the website 2 times per day, or 100 times for life, insert it into a new row called `return` and make it +1 every time when that visitor ( with the same IP Address ) visits the website. My question is, can someone explain to me how I can do that or show me some documentation online, that will be helpful.

Comment: use an [INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Keep in mind that using IP address to track visitors isn't necessarily accurate. Lots of people have dynamic IPs, lots of people use shared connections that would report all users in a single building with the same IP address.

Comment: Yes, but I need to secure my webpage as best I can. @droopsnoot

Comment: It's better to use two tables for performance. One keeped in memory to track all requests and second to store number of visits (in InnoDB) that would be incremented only once per day per unique ip. If request in memory table is the first one, then you increment record (or add as new) in second table. You can clear memory table everyday at midnight.

Comment: I agree with you. I will google now the solution you provide me. Thanks @Robert

Comment: For all who searched this system you can find here - https://www.edopedia.com/blog/how-to-create-website-visitor-counter-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a new Column to the table, maybe name it visits. then every time before you store the ip, check if the ip exists in the table first. If it exists, get value of column visits and add one the update the visits column with the new value.

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved this issue with Robert. He gives me a great idea and I resolve this issue. Thanks for help